# Retrieve outputs from a matrix job

Tags: github-actions

I am working on a repository that has a workflow whose last job gives outputs. That last workflow has a matrix that looks like below:

```
jobs:
  some-job:
    uses: some/action@v1
    # takes 'input_param' and 'appenv' as inputs and generates an output called 'example-output'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        env:
          [
            {input_param: valueA, appenv: production},
            {input_param: valueB, appenv: production}
          ]

  my-job:
    needs: [some-job]
    if: needs.some-job.result == 'success'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        instance: ["valueA", "valueB"]
    env:
      MY_OUTPUT: '${{ needs.some-job.outputs.example-output }}'
    run: echo "$MY_OUTPUT" # I need to be sure that I get the correct output for each ${{matrix.instance}}
```

I cannot run this action as it will execute in production a long-running pipeline, so I have no way of viewing contexts, etc

How can I be sure that `my-job` will fetch the appropriate output that corresponds to the inputs provided in the previous job's matrix?

EDIT: I tried this using `act` and both matrix instances return the same output. Basically, the instance that finishes later is overwriting the value written by the earlier instance

Comment: You can simply write a test workflow according to your use case and see if that works. Please add that in your question if it doesn't work as expected. From the above example, it seems like you expect the second job to work for every output of the first matrix job. IIRC, it doesn't work like that. You'll get the output from the last job only. You need to verify that. Alternatively, you can combine both jobs and that should work as expected.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/17245